# change local variable value in IDA Pro

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I need to change the value of local variable that is stored in stackframe in IDAPro 6.1:

```
var_1 = byte ptr -1
...
...
mov [ebp+var_1], 1
...
...
```

How can I change the value at `[ebp+var_1]` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the line that begins with `mov`?

Comment: @user1354557: No; i'm asking how to change local variable `var_1` value that is stored in stack

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking; can you be more specific?  In the function prologue, space is allocated on the stack for the local variables (e.g., `sub esp, 0x50`). At that point, the values of the locals are undetermined. Whatever values were previously stored on that part of the stack are still there. You could patch the binary to change the way the memory representing that particular local variable is assigned, but you'll have to provide more information.

Comment: Perhaps you are misinterpreting the first line you quoted.  When IDA says `var_1 = byte ptr -1` it doesn't mean that local variable contains the value of `-1`; it just means `var_1` is shorthand for `-1` in the disassembly. That is to say, that `mov [ebp+var_1], 1` line actually stands for `mov byte ptr [ebp-1], 1`.

Comment: @user1354557 : no i'm taking about changing memory at debug time  in dynamic analysis for a local variable in IDA ; actually i know how to modify memory in Ollydbg but not in IDA; The question simply is how to change memory address which that local variable is stored in stackframe

Comment: Oh, you mean within the IDA debugger. If you navigate to that stack address with in a hex view, you could manually rewrite the byte (hit `F2` to enable edit mode). There is probably a better way, however.

Comment: @user1354557: I do so but the change is not applied and after apply it revert back to original